# How to allow user log in each and every other authentication in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

User(`ROLE_USER`) Login url:

```
 www.aaa.com/user/info.do
```

Administrator(`ROLE_ADMIN`) Login url:

```
 www.aaa.com/manager/info.do
```

I use Spring Security.

I don't want the administrator to log out When a user logs in.(
also I don't want the user to log out When administrator logs in.

One man has User(ROLE_USER) ID and Administrator(ROLE_ADMIN) ID and uses one browser. 
I want to use two ID in one browser at the same time. 
ex)a website customer service center staff uses manager site and user site with two ID.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please elaborate, there is to little information here. Why wouldn't multiple concurrent users be supported?!

Comment: I think Spring Security has changed old Authentication information with new one in this class. 
---AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class---------
successfulAuthentication,unsuccessfulAuthentication

Comment: Again what is it you want?! We use spring security in production with 1000 concurrent users?! What is the problem/question you have? Currently it is to broad and contains to little information.

Comment: If a single user has multiple roles then it should simply work out of the box.

Comment: So what you basically want is a single browser session with multiple users?

Comment: Yes~! Yes  and users have different ROLE .

Comment: That isn't possible.. It only works with strictly separated browser sessions. Not inside the same browser, this has all to do how sessions work.

Comment: I will have to use just request Session for user side or administrator side. That will be different key value. Thank you very much M. Deinum.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's just a matter of assigning to administrators ROLE_USER in addition to ROLE_ADMIN. A single user can have more than 1 role (check getAuthorities() method in UserDetails interface).